# on Rails, is f.submit in a form_for newer than submit_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

some books or even the rails api uses

```
form_for ...
  ...
  submit_tag ...
end
```

and i found that the Rails 2.3.2 Scaffold uses

```
f.submit "Create"
```

instead...  and this is not in the rails api doc.  Is this a new
addition and is it suppose to replace submit_tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `f.submit` calls the `submit_tag` method under the hood.

It's in the context of the form "f".